# How to work with mpi-sppy when the probabilities of occurrence of random parameters are independent of each other?

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to learn mpi-sppy and I have some doubts.

I am studying the farmer example, from the documentation, https://mpi-sppy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#tutorial-farmer-example , which solves the problem from the book ntroduction to Stochastic Programming by John R.Birge and François Louveaux.

The example proposed in the documentation solves the simplest case of the many variants of the problem in the book and I have doubts about how to solve those variants of the problem with mpi-sppy.

First of all, the doubt that has arisen to me is how to create the scenarios if the probability of occurrence when the random events are independent?

In the example of the farmer the uncertainty is present in the crop yields, and it is assumed that there are three scenarios, "Good", "Average" and "Bad", and therefore if the "Good" scenario occurs, wheat, corn and sugar beet will have a good yield. But what if the yield of each crop is independent of the other crops, i.e. wheat has a "Good" yield, corn a "Medium" yield and sugar beet a "Bad" yield. This makes 27 possible scenarios. Should the 27 possible scenarios be explicitly defined?

Another question that has arisen is whether it is possible to use probability distributions instead of scenarios

Thank you very much for your time.